# python strange super declaration : multiple self

Tags: python, inheritance, init

Could someone please explain to me this strange line in [configobj.py](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/configobj.py), line 1190 :

```
Section.__init__(self, self, 0, self)
```

I don't understand the meaning of this multidecaration of self.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the `__init__` of `Section`:

```
def __init__(self, parent, depth, main, indict=None, name=None):
```

For some reason, the author of this code has decided to pass `self` several times to `Section`'s `__init__`. I haven't looked at the code in detail but this usually means objects can be constructed and in other cases these arguments will vary (i.e., they won't be `self` each time).

So for this particular call, the object represented by `self` plays a variety of roles and that's why the object is passed multiple times to the parent class's `__init__`. So to understand why `self` is passed multiple times you'll need to look at the purpose of the arguments and to see why they're the same in this case. It's conceivable that instances will be created where the arguments are different as those "roles" are then handled by different objects, and not all by the same object.

Comment: For what I understood from the code, it is to hold in one reference, the parent section, the current one and the child one if any (the context is a config files with section obviously :) ). I don't fully get it but I did grab it : so thank you. ;)